# How to capture python SSL(HTTPS) connection through fiddler2

Tags: python, ssl, https, python-requests, fiddler

I'm trying to capture python SSL(HTTPS) connections through Fiddler2 local proxy.
But I only got an error.

**code**

```
import requests
requests.get("https://www.python.org", proxies={"http": "http://127.0.0.1:8888", "https":"http:127.0.0.1:8888"},cert=r"FiddlerRoot.cer")
```

**The error**

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14090086:SSL routines:
SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Could anybody tell me how to fix the error except making verify False?
I've already accept "FiddlerRoot.cer" on Windows 7 system, but nothing changed.

- Python 2.7
- Windows 7

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
requests.get("https://www.python.org", proxies={"http": "http://127.0.0.1:8888", "https":"http:127.0.0.1:8888"},verify=r"FiddlerRoot.pem")
```

I've got to change .cer(DER format) file into .pem(PEM format). And I realized cert parameter was not that I wanted to use. The code above is a solution for me.

Comment: execute command in a console `openssl x509 -inform der -in FiddlerRoot.cer -out FiddlerRoot.pem`