# How to capture python https traffic in fiddler?

Tags: python, https, python-requests, fiddler

Python throws in errors when ever I try to do some data fetching task.
This only happens when I set fiddler to decrypt https traffic.
I have tried routing python traffic through 127.0.0.1:8888 and same with mozilla inorder to catch its traffic.
I also installed the certificate and trusted it via fiddler, I am not sure where I am going wrong.

```
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google.com', port=443):
    Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFIC
    ATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748)'),))
```

This above is the error I get whenever I try to fetch a page with requests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capture python SSL(HTTPS) connection through fiddler2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195834/how-to-capture-python-sslhttps-connection-through-fiddler2)

Comment: Already tried the solution, did not work out.

Comment: plz show us your code.

Comment: `requests.get("https://google.com")`, however code here isnt a problem even pip fails.

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR The requests library does not use the windows certificate store, it has it's own one (as per https://bugs.python.org/issue28547). This means that your fiddler MITM certificate is *not* available to python requests by default.

Your options are

1. Disable SSL verification (verify=False)
2. Add your cert via the REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE environment variable
3. Add your fiddler cert explicitly (verify='\path\to\cert')

More details can be found at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

On a side note, it does feel a little strange for requests to be using it's own cert bundle, rather than the platform supplied one - especially given all the browsers are happy to use the platform ones.

Comment: Hack: Set CURL_CA_BUNDLE env var to an empty string ... and it seems to disable verification.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by polhemic and Eric Aronesty, for testing purposes, you can set temporarily "CURL_CA_BUNDLE" to an empty string.

```py
import os
os.environ['CURL_CA_BUNDLE'] = ''
```